# Full name search in laravel 4?

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4, database

I have used this query for fullname seach.When using this query throwing error"Array to string conversion"

Please help me out sometime I receive error "BadValue $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects" when remove array from [$search]

```
$user=USER::whereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%?%', [$search] ")
```

Comment: did you end it with `->get();`

Comment: yes I have ended it with get

Comment: It is throwing error array_merge_recursive(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: Try `$user=USER::whereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%?%'", $search)`